# Private key is not generating from .p12 file

Tags: windows, ssl-certificate, openssl, certificate, private-key

I generated my .p12 file using the below command

> keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore mycert.jks -destkeystore keystore.p12 -deststoretype PKCS12

The above command successfully generated a 7 KB .p12 file. After this, i tried generating my private key using the below command

> openssl pkcs12 -in keystore.p12 -nocerts -nodes -out my_store.key

But it did not work. It created a file with 0 KB.

What am i doing wrong? I referred many blogs but the command is same. can someone please help/guide?

Comment: What about the passwords? Entries in jks and p12 are usually password protected. We're they asked by key tool and openssl?

Comment: Strangely no but the cert has a password. Not sure why it didn't ask for any password